# Bootstrap hastag active not working in tab

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

We have used this code for Tabs - URL change.

http://www.bootply.com/78032

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
  hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
  $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
  });
```

I have successfully implemented it. But I want to the hashtag tabs the user can click the back button to get back to their previous tab. How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery hashchange plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

with that you can do something like:

```
$(window).hashchange(function () {
  var tabpanel = $(location.hash);
  if(tabpanel.length > 0) {
    /* show tabpanel and hide all other tabpanels */
  }
});
```

Then you can change the tabs by simply putting the hashes into the href of the tab links, and even the issue with the browsers back button will be solved.

```
<a href="#tab1">
<a href="#tab2">
<div id="tab1">Tab Content</div>
<div id="tab2">Tab Content</div>
```